# uint256 input in RemixIDE

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to learn developing my first smart contract in order to use flash loans on aave. I have a problem regarding the amount input for the transaction.

I've a function asking for the amount of token I need and the type is uint256. When I type 10 I only receive 0.0000000000000001 by the flash loan. Why? Maybe it's a stupid question but I'm not understanding what's wrong.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: agpl-3.0
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

import { FlashLoanReceiverBase } from "./FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol";
import { ILendingPool, ILendingPoolAddressesProvider, IERC20 } from "./Interfaces.sol";
import { SafeMath } from "./Libraries.sol";
import "./Ownable.sol";

/*
* A contract that executes the following logic in a single atomic transaction:
*
*
*/
contract BatchFlashDemo is FlashLoanReceiverBase, Ownable {
    
    ILendingPoolAddressesProvider provider;
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint256 flashDaiAmt0;
    address lendingPoolAddr;
    
    // mumbai reserve asset addresses
    address mumbaiDai = 0x001B3B4d0F3714Ca98ba10F6042DaEbF0B1B7b6F;

    
    // intantiate lending pool addresses provider and get lending pool address
    constructor(ILendingPoolAddressesProvider _addressProvider) FlashLoanReceiverBase(_addressProvider) public {
        provider = _addressProvider;
        lendingPoolAddr = provider.getLendingPool();
    }

    /**
        This function is called after your contract has received the flash loaned amount
     */
    function executeOperation(
        address[] calldata assets,
        uint256[] calldata amounts,
        uint256[] calldata premiums,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    )
        external
        override
        returns (bool)
    {
        
        /*
        *
        *
        */

        // Approve the LendingPool contract allowance to *pull* the owed amount
        // i.e. AAVE V2's way of repaying the flash loan
        for (uint i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
            uint amountOwing = amounts[i].add(premiums[i]);
            IERC20(assets[i]).approve(address(_lendingPool), amountOwing);
        }

        return true;
    }

    
    
    /*
    * This function is manually called to commence the flash loans sequence
    */
    function executeFlashLoans(uint256 _flashDaiAmt0) public onlyOwner {
        address receiverAddress = address(this);

        // the various assets to be flashed
        address[] memory assets = new address[](1);
        assets[0] = mumbaiDai; 

        
        // the amount to be flashed for each asset
        uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](1);
        amounts[0] = _flashDaiAmt0;

        flashDaiAmt0 = _flashDaiAmt0;

        // 0 = no debt, 1 = stable, 2 = variable
        uint256[] memory modes = new uint256[](1);
        modes[0] = 0;

        address onBehalfOf = address(this);
        bytes memory params = "";
        uint16 referralCode = 0;

        _lendingPool.flashLoan(
            receiverAddress,
            assets,
            amounts,
            modes,
            onBehalfOf,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }
    
        
    /*
    * Rugpull all ERC20 tokens from the contract
    */
    function rugPull() public payable onlyOwner {
        
        // withdraw all ETH
        msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
        
        // withdraw all x ERC20 tokens
        IERC20(mumbaiDai).transfer(msg.sender, IERC20(mumbaiDai).balanceOf(address(this)));
    }
    
}
```

I'm deploying passing this address as parameter:
`0x178113104fEcbcD7fF8669a0150721e231F0FD4B`
it is the Lending Pool Addresses Provider contract taken from here: https://docs.aave.com/developers/v/2.0/deployed-contracts/matic-polygon-market.

When I try asking for more than 1000tokens I get the error. Hope this helps to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EVM doesn't support decimal numbers. So a common approach is to declare a number of decimals in the contract, and then include them with the stored values.

Example:
When a contract uses 2 decimals, value of 1 is stored as 100.

Aave protocol works with [ERC20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) tokens, where the standard defines a function named `decimals()` to return a number of decimal places.

Comment: So if I want to use Aave to flash loan DAI and I know that DAI use 18 decimals. If I would like to borrow 100 DAI I have to pass 100*10^18 as a parameter?

Comment: @thatguy Exactly. Just note that Solidity uses `**` (two asterisks) as the exponent symbol... The `^` (caret) is used for a different purpose - a bitwise XOR operation.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. If I try calling the function with this parameter 100**18 I obtain the following error:

invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="100\**18", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)

Comment: @thatguy If you're passing the number from Remix IDE, you need to pass the literal: `100000000000000000000` ... The `100**18` from your comment is correct for Solidity code (e.g. `uint256 number = 100**18;`).

Comment: I already tried as you're suggesting, this is what I obtain:

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": 3, "message": "execution reverted: SafeERC20: low-level call failed", "data": "0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000205361666545524332303a206c6f772d6c6576656c2063616c6c206661696c6564" }

Comment: @thatguy The "execution reverted" is caused by a runtime error, so the IDE has successfully accepted the number, sent a transaction ... and then the transaction failed because of a runtime logic.  Based on quick research, you might have a logical issue in your flow (unrelated to the input number): https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/safeerc20-low-level-call-failed-when-trying-to-stake-lp-tokens/6741/5

Comment: basically I have no logic in the smart contract, for now I'm just testing the flash loan. If I enter 1000, it works. If I put an higher number it fails. I'm struggling to understand why

Comment: @thatguy Possibly a limit on the side of the loaning contract. Feel free to post a new question with steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I updated the question inserting the smart contract I'm trying to use. Hope it helps

Comment: @thatguy Please provide repro steps so that answerers can do the very same thing as you did and get the very same result... That might include info on what network are you deploying the contract, what relevant actions have you done prior to this, which function are you trying to execute, how many tokens do the contract and the sender have, ... ?

Comment: I've solved, it was an error of mine. Thanks for your support

Comment: @thatguy Great. Please share the cause and how you solved it if you can, so that it might help others with the same issue.